# Scrolling to an anchor within a DIV on external click, via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a scrolling division which contains a list of hotels, grouped alphabetically. Above this division, I have an alphabetical index of links, which when clicked, I would like the corresponding alphabetical item to scroll upwards, within the division.

I've spent about an hour scouring the web and trying various techniques, and haven't found anything that does what I'm looking for, or at least something I can understand; I'm no jQuery genius.

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Show us what you have so far, and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Brad the answer below contains (broadly) the code I'm using, with the exception of a ul instead of a span for the index, and a h3 instead of div for the index item in the list.

Answer (score 17):

What you want is `element.scrollIntoView();` this will scroll the browser window/div to make an element visible on the page.

An example of this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qG3rm/) link

**Update**: Added a more complete dynamic example.

**CSS**

```
#container {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 50px;
}

.scrollto {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;  
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="scrollto">a</span>  <span class="scrollto">e</span> <span class="scrollto">i</span>

<div id='container'>
    <div id="a">a</div>
    <div id="b">b</div>
    <div id="c">c</div>
    <div id="d">d</div>
    <div id="e">e</div>
    <div id="f">f</div>
    <div id="g">g</div>
    <div id="h">h</div>
    <div id="i">i</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.scrollto').click(function() {
   $('#' + $(this).text()).get(0).scrollIntoView();
   // or $('#' + $(this).text())[0].scrollIntoView();
});
```

Basically in this example I created a small overflowed div causing it to have a scrollbar.

I then use `id` anchors on div tags inside of it to label the different areas in it.  I have a span outside the div to auto scroll to a certain anchor point inside the overflowed div when clicked.

---

**@Wayne Smallman**:  As per the html code in your comment, this is what you would use

```
$('div#index ul li a').click(function() {
    $($(this).attr('href')).get(0).scrollIntoView();
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YEqYp/1/)

Comment: Hi Jeff, and thanks for the suggestion. I'm already using a containing division called "preview" which has the same properties as "container". I've looked at the Fiddle, which works, but when applied the application, it doesn't work.

Comment: You'll need to provide more info and example code for anyone to help if you want a working example based on your page layout and specs.  If your using `ul` instead of `span` change the first part to `<ul><li class="sctrollto">a</li><li class="scrollto">b</li></ul>`.  if your anchors inside the container/preview are `h3` tags then what attribute are you using to identify that section?  `<h3 id="a">`?  If you do it that way then things should work without any change.  If you do something like `<h3 id="section-a">` then you need to use `$('#section-' + $(this).text()).get(0).scrollIntoView();`

Comment: Okay, the list:
<div id="index">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#index_a">A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#index_v">V</a></li>
  <li><a href="#index_w">W</a></li>     
 </ul>
</div>
And an anchor:
<div id="previewer">
 <h3 id="index_a">A</h3>
</div>
And that's it. If you need more, let me know.

Comment: Wayne, based on the code you provided in your comment I updated my question and added the solution for you to use at the bottom.  If this answer solved your question, please mark the question as answered by checking the box next to this answer. This helps build up your own reputation which will only benefit you and the community by letting others know what solved your problem.  Thank you.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for the reply! And apologies for my own late reply. I finally got this working in a way very similar to your own example. Thanks again!