# easiest way to achieve scrolling of content

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following structure - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2CJ2J/):
**HTML**

## Part1

- Elem1
- Elem2
- Elem3
  ...

## Part2

- Elem1
- Elem2
- Elem3
  ...

## Part3

- Elem1
- Elem2
- Elem3
  ...

- Part1
- Part2
- Part3

**CSS**

```
#container {
    float:left;
}
#controls {
    float:right;
}
```

When I click on the controls the page moves to the selected part. That's the standard behavior. What I want is that the page stays and only the content of `container` moves.
What is the easiest way to achieve this? Can it be done with pure CSS? Or maybe there is already a code snippet I could use?
My thoughts:
I can set overflow hidden for `container` and when clicked set negative margin-top for content with JS. Is it the right way to do it?

Comment: @Pay4m There might be more than that on the real page...

Comment: Looking for http://stackoverflow.com/q/8159264/1305911?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `overflow` does exactly this. If you set it to `auto` it will give `#container` it's own scrollbar, if it overflows. It will need a specified height though:

```
#container {
    float:left;
    height:600px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/2CJ2J/4/)

And if you wanted to make it 100% the height of your page:

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/2CJ2J/6/)

Comment: True, but notice that the page also scrolls as well - hiding the links

Comment: Only if you have the viewport smaller than 600px. 600px was an example, obviously the OP would alter this to his specifications.

Comment: @oGeez it is not working. click on `part3` and your `#controls` is not visible.

Comment: @Hiral See update. If the user wants the div to have its own scroll it's unlikely it'll ever be bigger than the view-port.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is position:fixed, like this:

```
#controls {
    float:right;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/2CJ2J/1/)

Comment: There might be more than that on the real page...

Answer (score -1):

You need to set #container to

```
position: absolute;
```

and then use JS to control the style.top of the element